# CMake make add_library depend on ExternalProject_Add

Tags: c++, build, cmake

**TLDR:** I would like to ask CMake to wait for `ExternalProject_Add` to complete before it attempts to move on to the next subdirectory and build a library that happens to use one of the files of the external project. In other words, I like to declare an external project as a dependency for a shared library.

**More Description:**

Suppose that my CMake project has two directories: `thirdparty` and `src`. My top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file has:

```
add_subdirectory(thirdparty)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

`thirdparty/CMakeLists.txt` contains multiple `ExternalProject_Add` commands. My original intention was to pull and build all these external projects and then move on to building my own libraries and executables in  `src`. Unfortunately, this didn't go as I planned:

One of my external projects is called `libsvm`. And my `src/CMakeLists.txt` has the following:

```
set(Libsvm_SOURCE_FILES
    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/thirdparty/libsvm/src/libsvm/svm.cpp
)

include_directories(
    ${Libsvm_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

add_library(
    mysvm
  SHARED
    ${Libsvm_SOURCE_FILES}
)
```

Now the problem I am facing with is that CMake is unable to find ${Libsvm_SOURCE_FILES}, apparently because this step is being executed before the `ExternalProject_Add` in my `thirdparty/CMakeLists.txt` file is executed.

I would like to declare this external project as a dependency for this library.

**Broader Question:**
Is there a clean way to force CMake to finish everything in first subdirectory before moving on to the next? If not, do you recommend that I make any change in the hierarchy and organization of my CMakeLists files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake expects every source file, passed to `add_library` or `add_executable`, to be existed unless it is marked as [GENERATED](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_sf/GENERATED.html). This property is *automatically* set for files listed as *OUTPUT* for `add_custom_command`. In other cases one need to set this property **explicitly**:

```
set_source_files_properties(${Libsvm_SOURCE_FILES} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
```